# Basic question about plural and possessive

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

I have multiple tables of different colors.

What is the correct saying if I want to talk about the colors of all the tables ?

> 1. The tables' colors.
> 2. The table's colors.
> 3. The tables colors.
> 4. The table colors.

I would say (1) is the correct answer but I cannot find a source to validate my assumption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Comment: I would say *whichever* choice you make from those 4, at least *some* readers would find it a bit "awkward". Just sidestep the issue with ***the colours of the tables***.